# Copy a range with multiple non-adjacent cells to another sheet on the same cells

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I wrote the code below which works fine except that it takes forever and looks as if Excel is having an epileptic seizure.

Any help with something less prehistoric would be much appreciated.

```
Sub Data()
Sheets("2").Unprotect "Joe"
Worksheets("3").Range("a").Copy
Worksheets("2").Range("D10").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Worksheets("3").Range("b").Copy
Worksheets("2").Range("L10").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Worksheets("2").Range("L18").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Worksheets("3").Range("c").Copy
Worksheets("2").Range("D11").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Worksheets("3").Range("d").Copy
Worksheets("2").Range("L11").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Worksheets("3").Range("e").Copy
Worksheets("2").Range("D17").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Worksheets("3").Range("f").Copy
Worksheets("2").Range("L17").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Worksheets("3").Range("g").Copy
Worksheets("2").Range("D18").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Worksheets("3").Range("h").Copy
Worksheets("2").Range("D19").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Worksheets("3").Range("i").Copy
Worksheets("2").Range("L19").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Worksheets("3").Range("j").Copy
Worksheets("2").Range("D20").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Worksheets("3").Range("k").Copy
Worksheets("2").Range("E22").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Worksheets("3").Range("l").Copy
Worksheets("2").Range("E23").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Worksheets("3").Range("m").Copy
Worksheets("2").Range("E24").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Comment: Please accept one of the below answers if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub Data()

Dim rng As Range

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With


Sheets("2").Unprotect "Joe"

With Worksheets("2")
    Set rng = Range("a")
    .Range("D10").Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value2 = rng.Value2

    Set rng = Range("b")
    .Range("L10").Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value2 = rng.Value2

'...and so on

End With


With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With

End Sub
```

Note that because you're using range names for a, b, c then there is no need to qualify them with a sheetname unless they are locally scoped.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer. It works perfecly although  I still do not fully understand as this is very advanced for me. But I got there after putting my head around a little bit.

Comment: Cool. Please mark it as answered if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of copy-pasting, you could also set the value of your destination cell equal to the value of your original cell. For example:

```
Worksheets("2").Range("D10").Value = Worksheets("3").Range("a").Value
```

To prevent the seizure like behavior in the application window of Excel, do as Excelosaurus suggested and turn off screen updating at the start of your macro. (And make sure to turn it back on at the end).

Comment: Had thought about this, but nothing guarantees that the named ranges such as "a" contain only one cell.

Comment: True that. I made the assumption it was 1:1. As jeffreyweir noted, you would want to use `Range.Resize` in the case where the named ranges are not a single cell.

Comment: Thanks a million for your answers. I used the expression above for every instance on the code and it works perfectly smooth. Fortunately for this application, all ranges were single celled but I simulated one with multiple cells and the Range.Resize worked fine too.

Answer (score 0):

Put `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the beginning of your sub, and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the end.

Comment: No sucess with this. I just added the first line straight after the Sub Name() and the second line right before the End Sub but it start the debugger right in the first line. Am I doing something wrong?